# how to center a relative div horizontally using jquery on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am initially centering div horizontally using jquery but when the window is resized it looks bad so what i want to do is keep it centered using jquery after the window is resized

is there a way to help?

**EDIT**

guys i have successfully made other elements centered but i am having another issue now :(

please check this
http://hrmanagementbradford.com/gallery/

and resize the window, you will see that the content doesn't get positioned correctly, i am trying to fix this for hours but can't find the solution please help with that

**EDIT**
solved! it was complex and my code is very specific so posting it here won't help :)
and
although i used jquery to center it but if we use the css thing then FutureKode's answer is best suited for me :)

Comment: Why don't you center the DIV with CSS (`width:XXXpx; margin:auto;`)?

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm not sure why you're doing this in jQuery rather than CSS...

Comment: you can see the code at the link i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using jquery to center horizontally when css can do it one line and it will stay in the center when the browser is resized:

```
div {
margin:0 auto;
width:800px
}
```

Comment: It would probably be wise to set `position: fixed` or at least `absolute` as well. Thsi will kepp it in the centre no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to centre a block element horizontally in CSS.

Like so:

```
div 
{
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: The attribute that actually controls the centering is the `margin` though. Nevertheless, updated for clarity.

Comment: That's true. But it dimensioning the element wasn't mentioned so I thought it may be useful to point that out. Good thing that you've updated your answer. +1

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: I was working on the assumption that the OP already had a width for the div considering they're already centering it with jQuery. It's always hard to tell without code samples though! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it dead-centered like this:

```
$('#elementID').css({
  position:'absolute',
  top:'50%',
  left:'50%',
  width:'600px',                 // adjust width
  height:'300px',                // adjust height
  zIndex:1000,
  marginTop:'-150px'             // half of height
  marginLeft:'-300px'            // half of width
});
```

Note that element will appear at the center but with scrolling it won't move. If you want to make it appear at center, you need to set `position` to `fixed` instead. However, this won't work in IE6. So decision is yours :)

---

You can also create quick simple jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.centerIt = function(settings){

        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.centerIt.defaults, settings);

        return this.each(function(settings){
          var options = $.extend({}, opts, $(this).data());
          var $this = $(this);

          $this.css({
            position:options.position,
            top:'50%',
            left:'50%',
            width:options.width,                 // adjust width
            height:options.height,               // adjust height
            zIndex:1000,
            marginTop:parseInt((options.height / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
            marginLeft:parseInt((options.width / 2), 10) + 'px'  // half of height
          });

        });
    }

    // plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
    $.fn.centerIt.defaults = {
      width: '600px',
      height: '600px',
      position:'absolute'
    }

})(jQuery);
```

And later use it like:

```
$('#elementId').centerIt({width:'400px', height:'200px'});
```

To center it when window is resized, you would use `resize` event just in case it does not center like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#elementId').centerIt({width:'400px', height:'200px'});
});
```

Comment: Don't you think that setting all those CSS in a CSS file would be better than setting it using jQuery?

Comment: @Robert: True but with jquery you have opportunity to use the `resize` event to center it just in case.

Comment: although this doesn't answer my question but is still worth a up vote!

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

   // reposition div again here

})
```