# Divs are not moving on window resize

Tags: html, css, window-resize

I want to move `div`'s on window resize. 
        I have three `div`'s inside one `div` (i.e container)

Eg:

```
      <div id="container">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="middle"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
```

It's aligned properly. But I want these `div`'s to move (but it shouldn't get overlap, I mean it should stop before it gets overlap) when I do windows resize.

```
This is how my CSS looks.
#container {
    text-align:center;
    width : 100%;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

> Blockquote

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: This how my CSS looks:
 #container {
    text-align:center;
}

#left {
    float:left;
}

#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#right {
    float:right;
}

Comment: @user2290579 Please, edit your question to add those details, thank you!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678839/how-to-center-a-relative-div-horizontally-using-jquery-on-window-resize

Comment: I have some questions about your problem... Do you know the width of each inner column? Is that width fixed or can vary? Do those columns be same width, or different? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create your div's and css design you like on this twitter bootstrap, this service can create responsive layout automaticly.

[twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not right. Instead of use `#left`, `#center`, `#right`, you need to use `.left`, `.center`, `.right`

When you use `#` it will select a html element with that id, this is why your css is just selecting `<div id="container">`, in your other divs you are using classes, so you use `.`

See a example :
http://jsfiddle.net/rELXZ/

More info about CSS Selectors you may find here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. here i updated wrongly .. bt in actual code i hv used properly .. the css is applying correctly. only issue is when i resize the div content its not moving.